# how to make a singleton uiviewcontroller class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Suppose i have a `ABC : UIViewController`. I would like to make it a Singleton class, as this view can be launched from various places in my app.

I started coding as below, but not sure how to proceed:

```
public static sharedInstance 

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: A view controller doesn't need to be a singleton to show it from various places in your app.

Comment: If you are mainly concerned with passing data around, then you can have a singleton class instead. But like @dan said, there's no need to make the VC a singleton

Comment: is it recommended to make uiviewcontroller as a singleton class?

Comment: To be more precise, you *should not* use a singleton VC as it is quite likely that state manipulations would get confused.